# Dismissing a badge notification does not work

Tags: bug, status-norepro, badges, notifications

Even if I dismiss a badge notification ("You have earned the ... badge for question ...") using the close button at the right of the message it gets redisplayed again and again when I refresh the page until I open a new session.

Working with Safari 5.0.3 (6533.19.4) on Mac OS X 10.6.5.

**Edit:**

I just created a new account at writers.se, and all three messages (Welcome, associated with, earned rights) kept appearing even after having gone to meta and back. Only jumping into a question and coming back to the main page made them go away. (Click them away using the close button for each, go into a question, and come back to the main page.)

Comment: Does it happen on other SE sites, or just on Apple?

Comment: @kyle - Haven't gotten a badge on another site lately. I will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: @kyle - it happens in other sites as well (maybe only beta sites).

Comment: @Ralph OK, since it's happening on multiple sites it's probably best to file a bug report on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. If you want, I can migrate this question there directly.

Comment: @Kyle - please do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't reproduce this -- have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Also note that clicking "back" will take you back to the previous state of the page, regardless of whether you have clicked the X to dismiss notifications.

Comment: I did not click "back" but refreshed the page by clicking on the title of the page. It happens reproducibly even after clearing the browser cache.

Comment: @Ralph your browser is incorrectly returning the cached page, there is no other way for this to happen